# PHP in Netbeans: Is there shortcut to generate the <?php ?> tags

Tags: php, netbeans

I've just started using Netbeans (7.1.2, php version) to work on a PHP project. Netbeans is really great for editing long stretches of PHP Code.

*But* in my view files where HTML is mixed up with short bits of PHP I am getting really tired of manually typing:

```
<?php  ?>
```

In Dreamweaver you just press a button to create these tags, but in Netbeans I can't find anything like a keyboard shortcut. Surely there must be one. Does anybody know what it is?

Comment: You can create it is tools, setting, keymap iirc

Comment: I've never used code templates, but I know they exists for this kinda stuff http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html

Comment: Use razor instead. then its only @{} :p

Comment: @chris - thank's for the link, it'll be really useful for what I want. I would tick it as an answer but can't because it's a comment.

Answer (score 16):

In Netbeans I had gone to **Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates** and looked through all abbreviations for the **PHP** language. There were lots and lots of abbreviations for pieces of PHP. But the `<?php ?>` tags weren't there.

After typing out my question it occurred to me that the place such abbreviations would be was for the **HTML** language instead of PHP. I looked there and there weren't any code templates at all. But it was simple to add one of my own (abbreviation: 'p', expanded text '`<?php  ?>`').

Now when the cursor's in the middle of some HTML, I type `p[TAB]` and my tags appear!

**Update**
Thanks to link from @chris in comment above I can change expanded text to `<?php echo ${cursor}   ?>` and the cursor ends up where I want it.

Comment: after writing the php opening and closing tag the short cut key work for code template that i create. but not work in html. 
Short-cut-key -> t
code-template -> `<?php echo ${cursor} ?>`

Comment: Suggest to add this template under HTML instead of PHP

Answer (score 1):

Looked through the guide and didn't see any

http://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but you can create a macro to do it yourself :)

You just have to click on **Edit -> Start Macro Recording** then you have to type in `<?php ?>` and afterwards click on **Edit -> Stop Macro Recording**.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one by default. The closest is typing `<?` and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> which will suggest you `<?php...`

Answer (score 0):

Just type **php + TAB** to have `<?php ?>` or **phpe + TAB** for `<?php echo ?>`

It's works for Netbeans 8 with default Php Package

If you want, you can change that shortcut on **Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates**; choose **HTML** on Language's select box.